# How to unlink all postgresql OIDs after integration tests with hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I try to run integration tests with Arquillian and Postgresql. I have this `persistence.xml` file which allow Hibernate to generate my database schema and pass all my tests:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="pu-it" transaction-type="JTA">
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/jdbc/testDS</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect" />
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
         <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false" />
         <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The problem is after testing, the OIDs previously injected in my  scripts with `lo_from_bytea(1, 'file')` are still stored in my database and during the next start of my tests I will get this Hibernate error:

```
 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index"
  D�tail�: Key (oid)=(1) already exists.
```

Is it possible to specify to Hibernate to destroy all OIDs like with the `SELECT lo_unlink(1)` query ?

Comment: Avoid large objects, they are fraught with problems.

Comment: We use vaccumlo to manage large objects and destroy orphans OIDs. I fix the problem by let the system allow loid with `lo_from_bytea(0, 'file')` and vaccumlo will detroy them. (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/lo-funcs.html)

Comment: But I'm curious, what should I use instead of large objects?

Comment: Use `bytea`, that doesn't have the problems large objects do.